# Show that $f(z) $ equals power series representation when $0 <|z-1| < 2.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I need to show that when $0<|z-1|<2$, the following equality holds:

$$\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-3)} = -3\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(z-1)^n}{2^{n+2}} - \dfrac{1}{2(z-1)}$$

I wrote 
$\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-3)}$ as the sum $-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{z-1}\right) + \frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{1}{z-3}\right)$.

So given that the equality holds, I only need to show that: $$-3\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(z-1)^n}{2^{n+2}}  = \frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{1}{z-3}\right)$$

I've written $\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{1}{z-3}\right)$ as $-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{3^n}$, but I can't find out how to proceed from here!

**Q:** How do I show that:

when $0<|z-1|<2$, the following equality holds:

$$\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-3)} = -3\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(z-1)^n}{2^{n+2}} - \frac{1}{2(z-1)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\frac{1}{z-3}=-\frac{1}{2-(z-1)}=-\frac{1}{2}\,\frac{1}{1-\frac{z-1}{2}}$$